# Getting Readiness problem failed due to connection refused in tidb pods only in tidb cluster

Tags: kubernetes, tidb

We have been running tidb cluster in k8s. and its working fine since. But suddenly i am getting  following issue only in new statsfull pods `tidb-tidb-1` after scaling tidb-tidb statsfulset. Interestingly tidb-tidb-2 is running. All others pd and tikv pods are also running fine.I have checked the pd url which is not reachable from problematic pods but fine for other pods.Can you please help me to solve this issue.

`tidb-tidb-1 logs:`

```
[2021/04/11 16:15:44.526 +00:00] [WARN] [base_client.go:180] ["[pd] failed to get cluster id"] 
[2021/04/11 16:15:48.527 +00:00] [WARN] [base_client.go:180] ["[pd] failed to get cluster id"]  [error="[PD:client:ErrClientGetMember]error:rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: i/o timeout\" target:test-tidb-pd:2379 status:CONNECTING
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Could you please show namespace information?
   kubectl get all -n  -o wide
2. Please check node information.
   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-isolation-restriction
3. Please check the network. If two nodes could ping successful?
   transport: Error while dialing dial TCP: i/o timeout